# Powershell script to rename files inside folders with the first 32 chars of the same files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename all the files inside the multiple subfolders of a folder, using powershell. These files contain a 32 character length string sequence and then a '-1', or a '-2' that I don't need anymore. So I want the new names of the files to be just their 32 characters.

Example:

BigFolder/
/Subfolder1 / abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab-1, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab-2, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab-3,
/Subfolder2 / abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab-1, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab-2, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab-3,..
etc.

They would need to be:

BigFolder/
/Subfolder1 / abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab,
/Subfolder2 / abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab, abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab,..

What I tried so far is:

```
    $sourceDirectory = "C:\Users\Desktop\Customers\powershellTests\ScriptOutput"

$filesToBeRenamed = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Recurse

Foreach($file in $filesToBeRenamed){
    $fileName=$file.BaseName
    $firstChars=$fileName.SubString(0,31)
    $filePath=Join-Path -Path $sourceDirectory -ChildPath $xmlFile.Name
    Rename-Item -NewName $firstChars
}
```

and this doesn't give any errors, but it renames just my initial root folder (BigFolder) in example.

Thank you!

Comment: In your `Join-Path`, you are going to want `-Path $file.Directory.FullName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, there is no need to try and combine the `$filePath` when renaming items. Also, you are forgetting the extension of the file if you rename it to only the first 32 characters.

Your code could be simplified to this:

```
$sourceDirectory = "C:\Users\Desktop\Customers\powershellTests\ScriptOutput"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\w{32,}-\d+$' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f $_.BaseName.SubString(0,32), $_.Extension} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The regex match in the `Where-Object` clause makes sure you are only searching for files that have a basename where there are at least 32 characters before the ending `-` and one or more digits.

Chances are here that you will try and rename files to names that already exist and in order to not receive a terminating error on that, I have added  `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. Now, when a rename is not possible because a file with that name already exists, the code simply skips that file.

Regex details:

```
\w          Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   {32,}    Between 32 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
-           Match the character “-” literally
\d          Match a single digit 0..9
   +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$           Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```